# Typescript - ignore import for a specific path

Tags: typescript, eslint

I would like to disable the Typecsript error 'cannot find a module' for a specific rule instead of having to keep adding this approach below for every file:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
// @ts-ignore
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-unresolved
import { myComponent } from '../brand/js/configs/my-component';
// @ts-check
```

The rule that I want to do: if the import has */brand/*, skip error checking, as this import will be resolved by Webpack at compile time.

For javascript files it can be solved only by adding a rule on eslintrc for 'import/no-unresolved'. But for Typescript I cannot find a way to do it.

Thanks :)

Comment: It should be possible to add it to the ignore list in your eslintrc https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/blob/main/docs/rules/no-unresolved.md#ignore

Comment: Something like `eslint import/no-unresolved: [2, { ignore: ['/brand/'] }]`

Comment: Or maybe you need to add `paths` to tsconfig's compilerOptions, if you know where the brands will be put.

Comment: I've added `eslint import/no-unresolved: [2, { ignore: ['/brand/'] }]` but it's only working on javascript files, no for typescript

Comment: the paths in the tsconfig's compilerOptions handle the path. But we are already handling it on Webpack. I just would like to ignore the error if the typescript find this name in the module. It's exactly what `eslint import/no-unresolved: [2, { ignore: ['/brand/'] }]` does, but for typecsript